# Dependency Injection with Quarkus

Tags: java, mockito, quarkus

I am new to Quarkus and I am trying to write a test for an object called `DummyReceiver`. I know Quarkus offers `@Mock` and other ways to create mock objects but this has the disadvantage that *every* instance in all tests will be replaced with the same mock and I don't want that. So I try to do a simple dependency injection.

Here are the most important configurations:

```
<properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus-plugin.version>1.13.3.Final</quarkus-plugin.version>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-universe-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>1.13.3.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <wiremock.version>2.28.0</wiremock.version>
    <spotless.version>2.11.0</spotless.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

My code is like this:

```
public interface DummyDependencyInterface {
  void store(String id);
}
```

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@ApplicationScoped
public class DummyDependency implements DummyDependencyInterface {

  public void store(String id) {
    System.out.println("DummyDependency stored: " + id);
  }
}
```

```
public class DummyMessage {

  private final String scannerInput;

  public DummyMessage(String scannerInput) {
    this.scannerInput = scannerInput;
  }

  public String getScannerInput() {
      return this.scannerInput;
    }
}
```

```
import ch.scs.mbv.vega.websocket.ScannerSocketMessage;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;

@ApplicationScoped
public class DummyReceiver {

  private DummyDependencyInterface dependency;

  public DummyReceiver(DummyDependencyInterface dependency) {
    System.out.println("DummyReceiver created with " + dependency.getClass().getName());
    this.dependency = dependency;
  }

  public void onProcessScannerMessage(@Observes DummyMessage message) {
    String scan = message.getScannerInput();
    dependency.store(scan);
  }
}
```

I then do the testing like this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque;

public class DummyDependencyMock implements DummyDependencyInterface {

  public LinkedBlockingDeque<String> ids = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();

  public void store(String id) {
    ids.add(id);
    System.out.println("DummyDependencyMock stored: " + id);
  }
}
```

```
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.enterprise.event.Event;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@QuarkusTest
public class DummyReceiverTest {

  @Inject
  Event<DummyMessage> messageEvent;

  private DummyDependencyMock mock;
  private DummyReceiver receiver;

  @BeforeEach
  public void setup() {
    mock = new DummyDependencyMock();
    receiver = new DummyReceiver(mock);
  }

  @Test
  public void test() throws Exception {
    String id = "123";

    messageEvent.fire(new DummyMessage(id));

    String storedId = mock.ids.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Assertions.assertEquals("123", storedId);
  }
}
```

The output shows

```
DummyReceiver created with scanning.DummyDependencyMock
DummyReceiver created with scanning.DummyDependency_ClientProxy
DummyDependency stored: 123
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :123
Actual   :null
```

Does anyone know what is wrong and how to fix it? Is there a better way to do it? Any advice is appreciated!

**Update: solution example**

The following example is for illustrative purposes and shows the simplest possible solution I could think of. `Example` is the class we would like to test:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@ApplicationScoped
public class Example {

  private Delegate delegate;

  Example(Delegate delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  public void doIt() {
    delegate.execute();
  }
}
```

The dependency we would like to mock is called `Delegate`:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@ApplicationScoped
public class Delegate {

  public void execute() {

  }
}
```

We can the write the following test to verify that `Example` calls the `Delegate`'s method `execute`:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@QuarkusTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ExampleTest {

  @Mock
  Delegate delegateMock;

  @InjectMocks
  Example example;

  @BeforeEach
  public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    example.doIt();
    verify(delegateMock).execute();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DummyReceiver` you are creating in your test is not known to the rest of application in any way.

If you want to mock `DummyDependencyMock`, there are multiple ways to do it in Quarkus, but  `@io.quarkus.test.junit.mockito.InjectMock` is by far the easiest.

Your code would look something like

```
@QuarkusTest
public class DummyReceiverTest {

  @Inject
  Event<DummyMessage> messageEvent;

  @InjectMock
  private DummyDependencyMock mock;


  @Test
  public void test() throws Exception {
    String id = "123";

    messageEvent.fire(new DummyMessage(id));

    String storedId = mock.ids.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Assertions.assertEquals("123", storedId);
  }
}
```

Note that the use of `@InjectMock` changes the mock for the specific test only - see [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#further-simplification-with-injectmock) for more details

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!! [This](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing) shows how to replace `DummyReceiver` with a mock using `@InjectMock`. But I don't want to mock `DummyReceiver`, I want to inject `DummyDependencyMock` instead of `DummyDependency`. And also I want to do it in this test class only, not in all test classes. Can you show me how to do that? What they do in the tutorial seems kind of pointless to me - why run a test on a mock object? I already know how it will behave since it is a mock. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @MikeElmwood " why run a test on a mock object" Of course you wouldn't test the mock object, they include some assertions in that guide I believe in order to show that these objects are indeed mocks, and that they return something different (set by Mockito.when()) than the real implementation would return.

Answer (score 0):

[geoand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2504224/geoand) got it almost right, his answer helped me to figure out the rest - thank you!!! Here is the code that works for me:

```
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;

@QuarkusTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class DummyReceiverTest {

  @Inject
  Event<DummyMessage> messageEvent;

  @InjectMock
  private DummyDependencyMock mock;

  @BeforeEach
  public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void test() throws Exception {
    String id = "123";

    messageEvent.fire(new DummyMessage(id));

    String storedId = mock.ids.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Assertions.assertEquals("123", storedId);
  }
}
```